# Which Protocol Java is using to store file at shared drive?

Tags: java

I am using following code to write the file at shared drive. I just want to know which protocol it is using to transfer the file? Is it RDP/TCP/SMB?

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("\\test_server\Folder_1\Folder_2\Folder_3")) {
    book.write(outputStream);
}
```

Here, book is nothing but XSSFWorkbook [org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook].

"test_server" is another machine in same network.

Comment: It's not up to you

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a java question.

`"\\test_server\Folder_1\Folder_2\Folder_3"` denotes a file name that is given to the **operating system**.

Meaning: java has **no** insight whatsoever what happens here. What kind of protocol the OS uses to connect to that server, in order to provide a *file handle* to java that the JVM can use to read/write to is **completely** out of control for that JVM.

So, in other words: the underlying protocol depends on how you configured the underlying operating system to connect to that network share.